# Is there a way to store generic structs in a map to reference them in a dynamic way?

Tags: go, generics, dynamic

I'm looking for way to store some objects (which have a common behaviour but related to different kinds of structs) and access them through a keyword. Something like this:

```
package main

func main() {
    printers := make(map [string] any)
    printers["floatPrefix"] = PrefixPrinter[float64]{""}
    printers["stringFormat"] = FormatPrinter[string]{""}
}


type IPrinter[T any] interface {
    PPrint(value T)
}

type PrefixPrinter[T any] struct {
    prefix string
}

func (printer PrefixPrinter[T]) PPrint(value T)  {

}

type FormatPrinter[T any] struct {
    format string
}

func (printer FormatPrinter[T]) PPrint(value T)  {

}
```

But then, it appears that my printers doesn't implement `IPrinter[any]`. Off course doing something like `printers := make(map [IPrinter[any]] string)` allows me to store them, but then I will have to cast any of the Printers, and that doesn't seem to be maintainable. So, would you know a way to implement this behavior, in order to have a single map to store them and that allows me to know that each element stored on it implements `IPrinter` interface?

Comment: This is a no go.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could make your way changing the interface to the print function to receive "any" and then cast it to the generic type, like:

```
type IPrinter[T any] interface {
    fprint(value any)
}

type PrefixPrinter[T any] struct {
    prefix string
}

func (printer PrefixPrinter[T]) fprint(value any)  {
    tValue := value.(T)
    
    *do stuff*
}

type FormatPrinter[T any] struct {
    format string
}

func (printer FormatPrinter[T]) fprint(value any)  {
    tValue := value.(T)
    
    *do stuff*
}
```

That way it would be OK to add different generic types:

```
func main() {
    printers := make(map[string]IPrinter[any])
    printers["first"] = PrefixPrinter[float64]{""}
    printers["second"] = FormatPrinter[string]{""}
}
```

---

Three things. One, you are trying to append to a map, which is not Go valid code. Also, you should not use "print" as a variable or function name, as it is a Go keyword.

And third, you can have a map or an slice of an interface type, but having generics it requires all elements to have the same generic type.

For example, taking your code and fixing for using a map of string keys and IPrinter values, with float64 generic type, you could do:

```
func main() {
    printers := make(map[string]IPrinter[float64])
    printers["first"] = PrefixPrinter[float64]{""}
    printers["second"] = FormatPrinter[float64]{""}
}
```

Notice that PrefixPrinter and FormatPrinter have float64, and the type is explicit in the map.